# Linear regression forecast underestimation

Tags: forecasting, multiple-regression

I have the following multiple linear regression model:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X1 + X2 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6 + X7, 
    data = my.model, na.action = na.omit)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-43.836  -1.507   0.010   1.485  46.231 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  -0.0244927  0.0245157  -0.999    0.318    
X1           -0.3484619  0.0134383 -25.931   <2e-16 ***
X2            0.1195273  0.0106940  11.177   <2e-16 ***
X3            0.1224587  0.0108849  11.250   <2e-16 ***
X4           -0.0010173  0.0028247  -0.360    0.719    
X5            0.5496942  0.0156319  35.165   <2e-16 ***
X6           -0.2287941  0.0145018 -15.777   <2e-16 ***
X7           -0.2315801  0.0146361 -15.823   <2e-16 ***
X8            0.0005465  0.0003595   1.520    0.128    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Residual standard error: 2.936 on 35849 degrees of freedom
  (12534 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared: 0.05968,    Adjusted R-squared: 0.05947 
F-statistic: 284.4 on 8 and 35849 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

The model is affected by multicollinearity but my question is about the forecast, so this shouldn't be an issue.

I checked the absolute values of my model forecast and compared against the actual Y absolute values. The average of the absolute predicted values is significantly lower than the absolute observed values mean:

```
> lm1.predict = predict(lm1, mydata)
> mean(abs(lm1.predict))
[1] 0.3294776
> mean(abs(mydata$Y))
[1] 1.206954
```

Does this mean that the linear regression variables I am using tend to underestimate the outcomes? Can any other conclusion be derived from this simple comparison?

**EDIT**

Another way to look at this is to calculate the absolute difference between each observation and the relative outcome:

```
> mean(abs(mydata$Y - lm1.predict))
[1] 1.208378
```

These are the diagnostic from the regression:

[image]

Comment: You have some outlying residuals.  What do your regression diagnostics say about their leverage and how many of them there are?  What do the diagnostic plots suggest about goodness of fit?

Comment: 1) Since you're not estimating the absolute values in your model, why are you using absolute values in the check?  2) If the mean of $Y$ is close to 0 (relative to the std. dev. of $Y$), all this comparison will tell you is that the predictions have less dispersion than $Y$, which is a consequence of the estimation procedure and not worth worrying about.

Comment: @jbowman I'm using absolute values because while I was reading through the predictions one at the time I noticed that the relative outcomes were all lower by substantial margin. I added the average of the absolute difference between each prediction and relative outcome to the question.

Comment: @whuber I added the diagnostics. If I'm not mistaken their impact shouldn't be very large given the number of data points.

Comment: The most revealing part is that the fitted values have a mean near 0, showing that @jbowman's surmise is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variance of predictions is always going to be less than the variance of the observations. The predictions are estimates of the means of the distributions conditional on the predictors. So, assuming the mean of the data is not too far from zero, you are comparing the dispersion of the means with the dispersion of the observations.

Comment: Of course! The variance of the regression line is always going to be smaller than the variance of the outcomes.

Comment: Rob, how did you get from `mean(abs(mydata$Y))` to the "variance of the observations"?  There seems to be a missing step in your reasoning. I think the edited information plays a crucial role here in revealing that the mean observation is close to zero.

Comment: @whuber By calculating the mean of the absolute values I'm effectively looking at a proxy for variance. mean(abs(values)) simply give us a measure of data dispersion. I'm not clear why you're referring to the simple mean of mydata$Y. I don't see it reported in the question.

Comment: Look a few lines above the Edit, Rob.  What's puzzling me is not the use of the mean absolute value of residuals as a proxy for residual dispersion, but its (explicit) comparison to the mean absolute value of the data ("the actual Y absolute values"), which is not a proxy for its dispersion except when it's known the mean data value is close to zero.

Comment: @whuber In that formula we're looking at the MAE, that is the average absolute error of the regression. I only added that value because I was trying to understand why the predicted values are lower that the actual observations. I'm not clear where is the puzzling part.

Comment: I'm hung up on this phrase, Robert: "The average of the absolute predicted values is significantly lower than the absolute observed values mean".  To see why this is puzzling, consider what would happen if, say, you were to add $100$ to every y-value.  The fit would be unchanged--it would merely increase the intercept by $100$.  But the mean absolute value would increase by almost $100$.  Thus you seem to be making a comparison that reveals nothing about the quality of the fit.  I think you get it right in the edit where you use `mean(abs(mydata$Y - lm1.predict))` instead.

Comment: @whuber. The mean of the predicted values is presumably close to the mean of the original data (identical if the predictions are actually fitted values). The mean of the absolute data is a measure of their dispersion shifted by some constant that depends on mean. The mean of absolute predictions is a measure of their dispersion shifted by roughly the same constant due to having roughly the same mean. Hence I thought this was essentially a comparison of the two dispersions.

Comment: Alas, that seems not to be the case, @Rob.  When the means are zero, then yes, the mean absolute value is a measure of dispersion.  But consider what happens when the shift is large enough to make all values (actual and predicted) positive.  Now the mean absolute values coincide with the means, giving us no information about the dispersions (absent special parametric assumptions).  Notice that no analog of the decomposition of mean square into squared mean *plus* variance exists for the $L^1$ (or other $L^p$) measures of dispersion.

Comment: @whuber I think I see your point now. If the intercept is large enough relative to the slope of the regression, then the mean of both the fitted values and observed values will tend to be close to the intercept and the difference between the two means relatively small. I'm going to add the intercept and mean values in the question, then the answer should maybe edited for clarity?

Comment: @whuber Actually the intercept is already in the question. Adding the simple mean of the fitted and observed values would just confuse more I believe.

Comment: The edited question is fine, Robert.  My latest comments were only an effort to clarify the logic behind Rob Hyndman's solution.

Comment: OK @whuber. I've edited my answer accordingly.